# Quantified statement

Tags: logic

For universal quantified , we just need to find a counter example to prove the statement.Isn't it ?So how about existential quantified?Isn't we just have to find at least one is true and proof it in general? Im quite confused with both of them on how to proof it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a universally quantified statement such as $\forall x.P(x)$, then we only need to find a single counterexample (i.e. some $x$ where $P(x)$ does not hold) to *disprove* the statement. However, in order to *prove* the statement, we have to show that $P(x)$ holds for any choice of $x$.

Conversely, for a statement with an existential quantifier such as $\exists x.Q(x)$, we only have to find a single witness $x$ where $Q(x)$ holds in order to *prove* the statement. However, to *disprove* the statement, we would need to show that $Q(x)$ does not hold for any $x$.

---

In fact, this relationship between proving and disproving is nothing more than the basic laws
$$\neg \exists x.P(x) \equiv \forall x.\neg P(x)$$
$$\neg \forall x.Q(x) \equiv \exists x.\neg P(x)$$

---

As an example, let $P(a,b)$ be $a/b < 1$, $A = \{2,3,5\}$, and $B = \{2,4,6\}$. Now, to *prove* the statement
$$\forall a \in A .\exists b \in B . P(a,b)$$
we would have to go through every $a \in A$ and for each of them pick a $b \in B$ such that $a/b < 1$. In order to *disprove* it, we would have to pick an $a \in A$ and go through every $b \in B$ and show that $a/b < 1$ does not hold.

In your comment you say let $a = 2$ and $b = 2$, then $2/2 \not < 1$. Sure, this is true, but in order to *disprove* the statement, we would have to have $a/b \not < 1$ for every choice of $b\in B$, you have merely shown it for a single $b \in B$. Indeed, if we take $b = 4$, then we get $2/4 < 1$, so we have not actually disproved it. Let's try to prove it instead. We go through the $a$'s one by one.

If $a = 2$, then we can pick $b = 4$ and we get $2/4 < 1$.

If $a = 3$, then we can pick $b = 6$ and we get $3/6 < 1$.

If $a = 5$, then we can pick $b = 6$ and we get $5/6 < 1$.

So we have gone through every $a \in A$ and shown that there exists for each of these $a$ a $b \in B$ such that $P(a,b)$. Hence we have *proved* that $\forall a \in A.\exists b \in B. P(a,b)$.

Comment: Now I have some ideas bout them. Thank you for answering

Comment: But what about both of  quantified statement in  statement ? I mean that universal and existential in the same statement. For example, for every aEA ,there exist bEB such that a/b<1. How to prove or disprove it ? @mrp

Comment: @newbie In that case, you simply "chain" the two. To *prove* such a statement, you will need to show that for every $a \in A$, we can find at least one $b \in B$ such that $a/b < 1$. To *disprove* it, you will need to show that there actually exists $a \in A$ such that for every $b \in B$, it is not the case that $a/b < 1$.

Comment: Sorry I still have a little bit confius on how to “chain” it together.So I come out with this thought. Let P(a,b) : a/b<1 where the domain a is A = { 2 ,3 ,5 } and the domain of b is B = {2 ,4,6}. ∀a∈A , ∃b∈B , : a/b <1. Note that every a∈A ,there exist b∈B ,such that a/b <1 Thus it is false for a=2∈A , b=2∈B , then 2/2 ≥ 1 . Is that how I should answer? @mrp

Comment: @newbie I have updated my answer.

Comment: Appreciate your help. thank a lot :) @mrp

Comment: So , what I can conclude from the combination of universal and existential in the same statement is we have to go through all for universal quantified , while for existential does not go through all of it .